# US Customs Pre-clearance in foreign airports

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, pre-clearance

Recently, I was traveling back to the US through Vancouver, BC, Canada.  I was delighted with the fact that I was able to get pre-screened through US Customs before even getting on the plane.  What other cities/airports offer this feature?  It sure saved a lot of time.

Comment: I hated this feature in Vancouver because the didn't let me get on a plane that transited via USA many years ago (-:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mostly Canada, but also a little bit in the Caribbean, and Shannon and Dublin in Ireland.

The complete list: [CBP Preclearance Locations](http://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance)

It doesn't *necessarily* save time, but it does allow you to fly directly to smaller US airports that aren't international airports and which don't have customs facilities.

Comment: Technically they are still international airports and have (at least minimal) customs facilities, and access to staff. It's just that the precleared planefulls never interact with those facilities or staff. If weird stuff happened (like a plane diverted) they could handle it.