# PR of Canada travelling to Cincinnati, layover at Detroit on a B1/B2 visa

Tags: transit, airports, layovers, short-connections, dtw

I am travelling to Cincinnati from Lester B Pearson Intl airport with a layover in Detroit. I have a B1/B2 visa. I am also a Canadian PR. Will I have to go through customs when I land in Detroit? If yes, my layover time is 48 mins. Is that enough time to finish going through customs and all other procedures?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You will go through customs in Canada, in what is known as *[pre-clearance](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/423)*.

Answer (score 8):

Most major Canadian airports have a US border post in them, including Pearson. For direct flights from these airports to the US (Detroit) you'll pass through the [US border pre-clearance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/423/us-customs-pre-clearance-in-foreign-airports) after check-in and before getting to the departure gate in Toronto. You'll want to arrive a little bit early to the airport in Toronto to account for the time it'll take you to go through the US border before your flight departs.

(A notable Canadian airport without US pre-clearance is Billy Bishop Airport in downtown Toronto. Porter Airlines' US-bound passengers complete immigration on arrival like those from any other non pre-clearance airport in the world.)

In Detroit your flight will arrive alongside domestic US flights inside the  departures security area. You can proceed directly to the gate of your connecting flight. You should have plenty of time.

Comment: I am afraid you are incorrect, in a nit-picky way. _MOST_ Canadian airports do not have a US border post in them. There are literally thousands of airports in Canada.

Comment: @DJClayworth there are [nine preclearance locations](http://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance) in Canada.  Does Canada really have 17 or fewer international airports?  The answer depends on the definition of international airport, which seems to be surprisingly difficult to pin down.  At least, there are 27 with a name that includes the string "international airport": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_airports_in_Canada

Comment: @CGCampbell of which nine currently have US preclearance.  See http://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance.

Comment: @phoog:  Note that one of those preclearance locations (Victoria) is a cruise ship terminal.  Only eight airports have preclearance facilities;  I counted an additional six airports (Billy Bishop, Victoria, Kelowna, Quebec City, Saskatoon, Regina) that have year-round cross-border service but no preclearance facilities.  (Plus a few smaller airports with seasonal service to places like Orlando.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert indeed I should have noticed that, since it is one of two preclearance locations that I've actually used.  I was thinking about it as I started to count but failed to keep it in mind as I got to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Region of Waterloo also has year-round cross-border services. But I don't think anybody is going to call it 'major'.

Comment: @phoog Most airports deem it sufficient that they have their country's customs and immigration service on site to process foreign arrivals, although plenty of US airports (e.g. Minot International Airport) have no foreign scheduled service, but do get private craft from Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean.  Conversely, Regina International Airport was simply Regina Airport for decades despite having scheduled US service plus Mexican, Dominican Republic and Cuban charters for many years.

Answer (score 1):

Pearson airport has a US customs pre-clearance. I have traveled from US-Canada-Back through Pearson several times on my student visa + Canadian PR. After you check in your bags at Pearson you'll go through security clearance and then US CBP (immigration). You might wanna arrive at Pearson atleast 3 hours in advance, since last time it took me 1 hour or so to go through US customs at Pearson. Once you clear US preclearance you are technically in US domestic terminal even though you are physically in Toronto. Thereafter you do not need to go through US customs and immigration again.

As to whether the 48 minutes at Detroit are enough, I would think so, based on extensive domestic travel experience. Really depends on how far you have to walk from gate to gate, in Detroit.

Check out this link for preclearance Canada locations: https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance